# ASP.Net call codebehind on $.ajax success

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a page (default.aspx) with codebehind. The a$.ajax url is getting a response from one place, and on its success I want to call the codebehind function.

(In case I made a mistake while obfuscating the code, the $.ajax works perfectly and I get the desired response).

How is this possible?

Code I'm using:

```
    jQuery.support.cors = true; // force cross-site scripting (as of jQuery 1.5)
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL,
                data: parameters,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    var resultCount = response.d
                    alert("*** RESULT ****" + resultFields);;
                    var string = StringReturn(); // the codebehind
                    alert(string);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("Unavailable");
                }
            });
```

Codebehind:

```
        [WebMethod]
protected static string StringReturn()
{
    return "StringReturn() success";
}
```

However, I'm getting error messages saying that StringReturn isn't a valid function.

Any help would be appreciated?

I've added the following lines of code to the page as advised:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"> </asp:ScriptManager>
```

I've also changed the code to call a javascript function on the Success event, the function being:

```
    function HelloWorlds() {

        alert("HelloWorld() method");
        message = PageMethods.StringReturn();
        message.toString();
        alert(message);
    }
```

however that doesn't appear to work. What am I missing?

Comment: I have several working examples [on my Github site](https://github.com/jupaol/SO-Answers/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%202012/src/SO/WebForms/WebForms_1/Topics/MicrosoftAJAX/PageMethods_ScriptManager.aspx) feel free to browse the code

Comment: the downvoter care to give a reason for downvoting this? just curous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a scripmanager on your page and then you can call it like this PageMethods.StringReturn()

Comment: never mind, got it to work, realised that I needed to use success and fail handlers to accept the returned string. Also, the codebehind functions needs to be public.

Thanks very much for your assistance.